# Is there a way to load pages in a flutter webapp only when they are needed?

Tags: flutter, web-applications, lazy-loading

I am trying to make a flutter webapp more performant and the only solution I can think of is to load the webpages lazily. Is there a way to do this in Flutter?

I tried using regular navigation but the webapp lagged heavily on some lower end devices when testing.

Comment: Since a Flutter web app is a single page app, can you explain what you mean "the webpages"

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks, I mean the widgets that represent the activity in a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://dart.dev/language/libraries under *Lazily loading a library*.  It takes some work on your part, but you can lazily load any portion of your app.

> Deferred loading (also called lazy loading) allows a web app to load a library on demand, if and when the library is needed. Here are some cases when you might use deferred loading:
> To reduce a web app’s initial startup time.
> To perform A/B testing—trying out alternative implementations of an algorithm, for example.
> To load rarely used functionality, such as optional screens and dialogs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the following yellow box is relevant: "Only dart compile js supports deferred loading. Flutter and the Dart VM don’t support deferred loading."

Comment: And how is that a problem?  The question was scoped to web apps.   Mobile apps and desktop apps don't load over the wire on each app start, like web does.  So deferred loading is pointless for a non-web app.

Comment: Consider a 2x2 grid of projects coded in Dart. In one dimension, pure Dart vs Flutter; in the other dimension targeting JS or VM. 'Flutter' rules out one column, 'VM' rules out one row, leaving just one quadrant: pure Dart targeting JS (i.e. the way we used to use Dart for web before Flutter).

Comment: You misread the poorly worded sentence.  The intent is that flutter apps on mobile cannot have deferred loading, and we understand that.  But flutter web apps compiled to javascript do indeed support deferred loading.  I could find nothing disputing that.  (I believe the sentence was written before Flutter web was a thing.)